# confusion about asynchronous programming

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

```
class Program
{
    public delegate void ss(string s);

    public static void print(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("asynchronous thread..."+s+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ss s = print;

        Console.WriteLine("Main thread..." + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

        IAsyncResult result = s.BeginInvoke("hello", null, null);

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main...thread..."+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

        Console.WriteLine("Main...thread...after sleep" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        Console.WriteLine("Main...thread...after sleep..." + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

        s.EndInvoke(result);
```

Output is:

```
Main thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
**asynchronous thread...hello 4:20:01 PM**  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
Main...thread...4:20:01 PM  
**Main...thread...after sleep4:20:04 PM**  
**Main...thread...after sleep...4:20:04 PM**
```

My question is why sleep method doesn't count in asynchronous method?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by your question?... Try add an output after your sleep in the Async method, that might make things more clear to you... (Sleep is not across all threads, it's only for the thread executing the code containing the sleep).

Comment: oh! Thanks Jens, these two are in different thread...one more questions, does it will get some potential issues if i don't use endInvoke() ?

Comment: @Darkterror_jl results of delegate invocation will be cached until you call EndInvoke. So, it's better to call it to free resources quickly (btw documentation says that you should always call it)

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy : got it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why sleep method doesn't count in asynchronous method?

It does encounter. After writing line `asynchronous thread...hello 4:20:01 PM` your background thread goes to sleep, but main thread continues to print messages. Add message after background thread has awaken to see that Sleep worked:

```
public static void print(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine("async thread..." + s + DateTime.Now.ToString("T"));
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("async thread after sleep " + DateTime.Now.ToString("T"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats right, I've add `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` and see that's different thread..

Comment: @Darkterror_jl yes, your background thread was sleeping while main thread continued execution